# Best way to calculate similarity between rows of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, cosine-similarity

I'm a Python noob, so sorry if the question sounds too basic for anyone reading.

I've this `matrix` of type `numpy.matrix` (I omit all the code that generates this `matrix`):

```
[[0.         0.2342598  0.         0.         0.         0.31308172
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.31308172 0.
  0.         0.86549525 0.        ]
 [0.         0.2342598  0.         0.         0.         0.31308172
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.31308172 0.
  0.         0.86549525 0.        ]
 [0.22575551 0.72375361 0.         0.19345532 0.22575551 0.19345532
  0.         0.38691064 0.19345532 0.19345532 0.19345532 0.19345532
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.22575551 0.72375361 0.         0.19345532 0.22575551 0.19345532
  0.         0.38691064 0.19345532 0.19345532 0.19345532 0.19345532
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.64936739 0.         0.28928716 0.         0.
  0.39985833 0.28928716 0.28928716 0.28928716 0.         0.28928716
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.26302218 0.50593649 0.37991833 0.22539002 0.26302218 0.
  0.31153847 0.11269501 0.11269501 0.45078005 0.         0.11269501
  0.18995916 0.         0.18995916]]
```

By using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` I easily get the similarity between two *rows*.

For example, by coding `cosine_similarity(X[0], X[1])` I get a `numpy.ndarray` that contains only one element: a `float` value between `0.0` and `1.0` that represents the level of similarity between `X[0]` and `X[1]`. I finally get the value inside the array this way `cosine_similarity(X[0], X[1])[0][0].item()`.

Problem is I don't need to compare only two rows for similarity: I need to compare `X[0]` to any other row and find the most similar to `X[0]`.

What's the best (more *pythonic*, performant, elegant, practical...) way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Update: sorry, I forgot to mention what actually works for me:

```
def calculate():

    h = 0.0
    e = -1

    for i in range(1, len(m)):
        if cosine_similarity(m[0], m[i])[0][0].item() >= h:
            h = cosine_similarity(m[0], m[i])[0][0].item()
            e = i

    return e
```